# When are the exact start and end of the calendar year from the IRS standpoint, regarding timezones?

Tags: united-states, taxes

The calendar year from the IRS standpoint starts on January 1 and ends on December 31. But what is the timezone?

For example, if a US taxpayer converts an after-tax 401(k) to a Roth 401(k) on December 31 at 23:59 [UTC−11:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9211:00), 2017, does that count as December 31, 2017 or January 1, 2018?

Comment: When I logged into Fidelity at less than a hour before midnight **local time** (but was 2018 Eastern Time), only 2017 contributions were available.

Comment: It's a different thing but might be usable as an analogy: for _e-filed returns_ IRS normally accepts the timestamp your return is (electronically) received by the authorized 'Transmitter' (e.g. Intuit etc.) adjusted to the timezone of your residence, see https://www.irs.gov/e-file-providers/electronic-postmark

Answer (score 17):

I don't know of a federal rule regarding this, but in my experience financial transactions are based on the point of view of the transacting bank. In other words, whatever date the bank statement shows would be the official date.

Comment: Common sense says this must be the right answer since your bank statement is generally the evidence you'd expect to rely on should questions arise about your transaction...

Comment: @Mehrdad Thanks. What if I can prove that the taxable event to place on December 31 at 23:59 UTC−11:00, 2017? (e.g., email  from the institution managing the 401(k) plan confirming that the action from the taxpayer was received). Does that count as December 31, 2017 or January 1, 2018? As a side note, the in-Roth 401(k) conversion was just an example. Another example: the taxpayer won 1kUSD at the casino on December 31 at 23:59 UTC−11:00, 2017.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - for transactions that banks report to the IRS, if what the bank reports doesn't match up with what you report, then the IRS will likely send you a letter with an updated tax liability and it would be up to you explain to them why you believe the bank date is "wrong". Similarly, for things that are not reported, then if audited it would be up to you explain to the auditor why your dates don't match up with the bank statements. Perhaps your example email documentation would satisfy them, perhaps not. (It seems reasonable to me.)

Comment: @TTT thanks good to know, but we go back to the timezone issue: which timezone does does IRS use?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - again, I don't think the IRS uses a timezone. What is reported is based on whatever timezone the bank is using, which varies by bank.

Comment: @TTT if the taxpayer disagrees with the date stated on the bank statement, and provides as  evidence to the IRS the confirmation email that they received from the bank, is it up to the taxpayer to decide which timezone they want to use?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - To reiterate me previous comment: you report whatever you want. The bank reports whatever they want. If they match, all is (usually) good. If they don't match, the IRS may contact you for clarification and then it's up to you to explain why what you reported differs from the bank.

Comment: @TTT I see. I just wanted to understand if the IRS has any time zone in mind (which could depends on the taxpayer location, for example). From your answer and your comments, I understand that as far as you know the IRS doesn't have any guideline on that matter. Thanks for your feedback!